# Server Side Blazor + Kestrel + Windows Auth = Crash

Tags: windows-authentication, kestrel-http-server, blazor

I am trying to setup windows Auth using kesterel on blazor server side.I have the progam setup like this:
I am using version 0.6.0 of Blazor server side and latest release of VS 2017.
Using the out of the box blazor temnplate. You can see that I enabled "windows Auth" in BuildWebHost of 'Program.cs". If I comment out options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous line, everything works, of course.

Blazor.Web.server

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();            
    }
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseHttpSys(
                                    options =>
                                    {
                                        options.Authentication.Schemes =
                                           AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM; 
                                        options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;                                          
                                    })
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
            {
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
            // Since Blazor is running on the server, we can use an application 
            service
            // to read the forecast data.
            services.AddSingleton();
            }
            public void Configure(IBlazorApplicationBuilder app)
            {
            app.AddComponent("app");
            }
        }
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
    { 
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }   

        public static IWebAssemblyHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            BlazorWebAssemblyHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .UseBlazorStartup<Startup>();
    }

public class HttpContextAccessor
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public HttpContextAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
               _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public HttpContext Context => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }
```

Auth.cshtml

```
using System.Net.Http
@Inject Blazor.Web.App.HttpContextAccessor HttpContext
@page "/two-way-data-binding"

Logged in User: @HttpContext.Context.User.Identity.Name
```

I get the following error when navigating to Auth.cshtml

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
HResult=0x80131622
Message=Safe handle has been closed
Source=System.Private.CoreLib
StackTrace:
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
at Interop.Advapi32.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle TokenHandle, UInt32 TokenInformationClass, SafeLocalAllocHandle TokenInformation, UInt32 TokenInformationLength, UInt32& ReturnLength)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetTokenInformation(SafeAccessTokenHandle tokenHandle, TokenInformationClass tokenInformationClass, Boolean nullOnInvalidParam)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_User()
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.b__46_0()
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.<>c__DisplayClass62_0.b__0(Object )
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedInternal(SafeAccessTokenHandle token, Action action)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(SafeAccessTokenHandle safeAccessTokenHandle, Action action)
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetName()
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Name()
at Cloud.WebUI.App.Pages.TwoWayDataBinding.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Rendering.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Rendering.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Rendering.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
```

This is also created as a "issue" @ [Blazor Issue # 1596](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1596)

Comment: Mate, your code is badly formed, with many parts missing. I guess you're not only new to Blazor, but to ASP.NET Core, right ? If you are an ASP.NET developer, your first step to learn Blazor is to learn the Core flavor. It's something else, believe me. By the time you have a reasonable command of this framework, and your code won't contain something like this: services.AddSingleton(); Blazor would be at its last developmental shaping phase, and you won't need to learn obsolete stuff. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, this was the default blazor template. I removed the "weatherforecastservice"  from DI as it does not add value. Most of the code is boilerplate except for the "HttpContaxtAccessor" part. Looks like blazor does not pass the usercontext to the server via signalR or may be it gets disposed off prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, there is no need for your custom class **HttpContextAccessor** as it does not add any value.

Be sure to add the following line to your **ConfigureServices** method of the **server's Startup.cs**

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then you are fine and can use the **HttpContextAccessor** in your Blazor app the following way:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
User: @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

Set windows authentication to true in your **server's project** web server settings (the last area in debug settings).

I'm using Blazor 0.7.0